# Lighting needed for 2-D Stop-Motion Video

Tags: lighting, stop-motion

What sort of lighting setup do I need for 2-D stop motion?

I don't have a lot of space, so the canvas area won't be huge. I will probably use 11" x 14" heavy 11" x 14" matte paper. All the animation will consist of cutouts and be flat (not sure if this was obvious).

I'm thinking of using 2 cheap clamp lamps from Home Depot, and positioning them at the ends of long side of the paper. Not sure if I should diffuse or not.

Then I'll put my camera above the light source, to avoid getting my camera's shadow in the snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only one who can determine the setup is **you**.

This is becouse you don't need a technical issue like eliminationg shadows while reproducing a painting.

You probably need:

- the texture of the paper to be noticable, or not.
- the wrincles of the cutout paper, or not.
- some shadows to make emphasis that is not computer generated, or not.
- a light that simulates a real light on your scene. Imagine that you are making a shoot in the woods. Probably make a cutout for shadows simulationg a forest, or not.

At the end. Make some shoots and make choices.

---

Just some technical notes.

- Let the lamps to warm up for some minutes before making the shoots.
- Define a white point.
- Finish a scene. Make a new one in a diferent day.
- Use manual control on the camera.
- Use markers for the camera position and light positions (and angles)

Comment: A VERY important point it to use lighting which has a wide gamut output. Some lamps (eg cheap ccfl) have a very odd output and are missing a lot of wavelength - It may not be obvious to the eye, but the  shots can look very flat. 
I learned this while trying to photograph oil and watercolour paintings to print for a customer.

Comment: Good point. You need to balance things like this wavelength and the temperature it generates for example.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for the in depth response Rafael. Would you have any suggestions on a inexpensive light that simulates real light? I'm thinking 2 swing arm lamps with 2 60W Equivalent Daylight (5000K) light bulbs.